# calling an array of gameobjects' script called 'apple' from a script called 'money'

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

(In unity 2D)So I have a script for the amount of money and apples I have in my game and want to make more than 1 game object have the amount of apples script. btw there IS a void TransferMoney and IS public. I do this, and I need to transfer the amount of money i have to the apple script but because it's an array it does the following error: (55,16): error CS1061: 'apple[]' does not contain a definition for 'TransferMoney' and no accessible extension method 'TransferMoney' accepting a first argument of type 'apple[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Here's the money script:

```
public class numberofmoney : MonoBehaviour //script in the Text UI "amount of money" {

 static public int scenemoney;
 public string house;
 public string shopString;

 public TMP_Text moneyText;
 public cookie1 Cookie;
 public apple[] apples;
 public void BoughtApple(int currentAOM)//aom stands for 'amount of money'
 {
     scenemoney = currentAOM;
 }
 void Awake()
 {
     apples = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<apple>();  //finds apple
 }
 void Start()
 {
     Scene cookie = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
     house = cookie.name;    //checks scene and does part of converting to string
     Scene shop = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
     shopString = shop.name; //checks scene and does part of converting to string

 }
 public void forCookie(int money)
 {
     scenemoney = money;
 }
 void Update()
 {
     string scenemoneystring = scenemoney.ToString();
     moneyText.SetText(scenemoneystring); //Converts money and sets text
     if (house == "House") {     //transfers money between scripts #1
     Cookie.transferMoney(scenemoney);
     }
     if (shopString == "store") { //transfers money between scripts #2
     apples.TransferMoney(scenemoney);
     }
 }

}
```

and apples script:

```
using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.UI; using TMPro;

public class apple : MonoBehaviour {

 public string appleString;
 public int publicMoney;
 public int Apples;
 public NumberOfApples numberOfApples;
 public TMP_Text tmp;
 public numberofmoney NumberOfMoney;
 void Awake()
 {
     numberOfApples = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<NumberOfApples>();
     NumberOfMoney = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<numberofmoney>();
 }
 public void TransferMoney(int money) 
 {
     publicMoney = money;
 }
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trigger)
 {
     if (publicMoney >= 10){
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
         Apples++;
         publicMoney -= 10;
         appleString = Apples.ToString();
         tmp.SetText(appleString);
         NumberOfMoney.BoughtApple(publicMoney);
     }
     numberOfApples.transferApples(Apples);
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate over the array (`for` or `foreach`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what I can see, you're doing:

```
apples.TransferMoney(scenemoney);
```

but apples is an array of the class apple, you can't call the "transferMoney" method, you need to iterate each object of the array and call the transferMoney method individually.

```
foreach(apple a  in apples){
    a.TransferMoney(scenemoney);
}
```

hope that helps!

Edited: copy paste error called by derHugo

Comment: You have a typo again ;) it should be `apple.TransferMoney` ;)

Comment: This worked, thanks! I had to look up what foreach loops do, I guess you learn something new everyday!

Comment: Awesome, you can use any type of loop, I used a foreach just because.